# Autoconfiguration on programmable Xbee modules

Tags: xbee, zigbee

Non-programmable Xbee modules should be configured through a PC (with XCTU) or other devices like Arduino... but can the programmable xbee modules (like xbee-pro zb s2b) autoconfigure themselves, without being connected to another device like a PC or Arduino, by running code stored in their memory?

I mean, can they run orders like the ones you run through XCTU but programming them in the internal memory code? Like scan energy of every channel, select a channel, set a PAN ID, configure the different parameters of the device...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the development kit includes an API for sending AT commands from the co-processor to the radio on those boards.

There's also a passthrough mode that relays the host computer serial port through to the radio processor, which can help with initial setup/configuration of the modules like you might do during manufacturing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> I mean, can they run orders like the ones you run through XCTU but programming them in the internal memory code?

No. You can not program a sequence of orders/commands into the internal memory of the device. To do anything meaningful the device needs to be "driven" from a host PC or MCU that can send the AT Commands.

If you want 1 device solution that does not require a Host MCU then you will need to use a ZigBee SoC (System on Chip), such as the CC2538 - http://www.ti.com/product/cc2538 running a ZgBee SDK (Software Development Kit) - http://www.ti.com/tool/z-stack (ZStack-Home). However this will require you to develop the ZigBee application SW.

Regards,
TC.